# I want to store a javascript variable to a text file on server (for highscore)

Tags: javascript, html

So I am expreimenting with making javascript games. I think I have gotten the hang of the basics of the canvas element, but I cant figure out how to store high scores! So far I have used "localStorage" to store highscores player's browser, but I want to store them on the server, so that everyone can see them.

Keep in mind that I am a complete newbie when it comes to servers and server side programming. Its very possible that I am asking the question wrong, but I think you get the idea :p

Help is MUCH appreciated, I have searched around a bit already, but I cant find any direct answers.

Comment: You might want to Google around for "databases" or "filehandling on the server". You might want to include "HTTP POST" and "AJAX" while you're at it.

Comment: Probably you dont use PHP so you can use AJAX for communicating with a server.

Comment: Google `creating a database` and `php insert to database`. Look for `PDO` or `mysqli`.